# Cannot remove sprite from new CCNode class

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am creating a small game where objective is to tap and destroy mouse. I created a separate mouse class for it.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
@interface Mouse : CCNode <CCTargetedTouchDelegate> {
    CCSprite *sprite;
    HelloWorldLayer *HelloLayer;
}
-(id) initWithGame:(HelloWorldLayer *)aGame;
-(void) runFloatAction;
@property(nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *sprite;
@property(nonatomic, retain) HelloWorldLayer *HelloLayer;
@end
```

I am initializing like this in .m file:

```
-(id) initWithGame:(HelloWorldLayer *)aGame{
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        self.sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mouse.png"];
        self.sprite.scale = 0.3f + CCRANDOM_0_1() * 0.5f;
        self.sprite.position = ccp(CCRANDOM_0_1() * 480, CCRANDOM_0_1() * 320);
        self.HelloLayer = aGame;
        [aGame addChild:sprite];

        [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self 
                                                         priority:1 
                                                  swallowsTouches:YES];

        //[self runFloatAction];
    }

    return (self);
}
```

I want to remove sprite on tap. For which I am using this code in .m file: -

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    if ([self containsTouchLocation:touch]) {
        [self.sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I am not able to remove sprite. Logically, we have to remove sprite from parent. But, its not working in actual.

Comment: that should work. but remember that you are retaining that sprite (you property is retain). you can do self.sprite = nil to release the sprite after removing from its parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I did self.sprite = nil and it works for me..

Comment: if you use CCNodes that are added as childs, its preferable to declare property assign and not retain. the sprite is retained by its parent so you dont need to remember to actually release the sprite after removing from its parent

Comment: ahh ok.. Thanks for help.. I was stuck owing to the same problem from 1 week..

Answer (score 0):

The way I structure my classes is to have the Mouse class as a subclass of CCSprite. If you handle the touch events in the main game class than you just remove the mouse. You also need to enable touch events if you haven't done that.

I recommend you do the above and put this in your game class.

```
[self setIsTouchEnabled:YES];
Mouse *myMouse = [Mouse spriteWithImage:@"Mouse.png"];
[myMouse setPosition:CGPointMake(160, 240)];
[self addChild:myMouse];
```

Then just handle the touch events in your game class.